# Issue with meta viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'd like to do my front-end framework responsive but I just got an issue... I have a `margin-right` to my body...

My meta :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

My screenshot (iPhone): https://space.zeo.net/g/3vgkg

My screnshot (Mac Book Pro): https://space.zeo.net/g/51bm2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a layout based on Bootstrap or a similar framework, they will have built margins at narrow screens.

When I want an element to extend full width, I usually remove this by adding negative left and right margins at the appropriate breakpoint, and then add some padding so that text has some breathing space left and right.

Something similar to the following might work for you:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .nav{
   margin:0 -20px 0 -20px;
   padding:0 20px 0 20px;
  }
}
```

Without seeing a URL, it's difficult to be more specific but hopefully this will get you started.

Good luck!